# Serialize shell command in Terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, kubectl

When using Terraform to run `kubectl` with local-exec provisioner under *null_resource* I get the following error:

> exit status 1. Output: error: open /Users/myuser/.kube/config.lock: file exists

since I'm running the *null_resource* with count it looks like Terraforms spawns several `kubectl` commands in parallel, and `kubectl` doesn't like this. 
Are you familiar with a way to serialize the command in a local-exec to prevent this issue? any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share your resource configuration?

Answer (score 1):

When using the local-exec provisioner with a null_resource, we've found that you can serialize the commands in the following manner;

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      export KUBECONFIG=/root/.kube/config
      kubectl create -f resource1.yml
      kubectl create -f resource2.yml
      unset KUBECONFIG
    EOT
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `null_resource` with count, rather build the doc or command in a var using https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html and execute `kubectl` once.

Kubectl with YAML can eat several docs at once, and if you simply specify a resource id they can be listed after `kubectl` with spaces.