# GCP Cloud Build and Terraform integration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am running Terraform using Cloud Build.

```
step {
  name = "hashicorp/terraform:1.0.1"
  args = ["init"]
  dir  = env/dev
}
step {
  name = "hashicorp/terraform:1.0.1"
  args = ["plan"]
  dir  = env/dev
}
step {
  name = "hashicorp/terraform:1.0.1"
  args = ["apply", "-auto-approve"]
  dir  = env/dev
}
```

in my terraform code there is a local-exec command which runs some Linux commands and one gcloud command.

```
resource "null_resource" "gcloud" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = <<EOT
     .
      some Linux commads
     .
     gcloud pubsub topics list 
  EOT
  }
}
```

after Terraform Apply,  it gives me:

```
exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: gcloud: not found
```

to solve this issue I used gcloud module :

```
 module "gcloud" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google"
  version = "3.1.0"

  create_cmd_endpoint = "gcloud"
  create_cmd_body        = "version"
  destroy_cmd_body      = "gcloud"
  destroy_cmd_body       = "version"
 }
```

now I have two errors:

```
[7:47 p.m., 2022-11-13] Milad: exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: curl: not found
[7:47 p.m., 2022-11-13] Milad: exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: gcloud: not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sosh, do let me know if the below information was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have mentioned above seems to be due to the “gcloud” module not being incorporated properly and thus the command referencing the sub command results in this kind of error.  The “gcloud” module execution should make sure that “gcloud” is decompressed and set up in the proper order during the setup.
I would recommend you try [the latest version of terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest) which seems to address this issue.
Also check these similar examples:

- [Multiple commands in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297188/terraform-unable-to-run-multiple-commands-in-local-exec)
- [Serialize shell command in terraform local exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347314/serialize-shell-command-in-terraform-local-exec-provisioner)